# Wake up vs woke up

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Which one is correct?

> I woke up at 3 everyday
>
> I wake up at 3 everyday

Comment: What is the context? What do you want to communicate? Both sentences are possible, so without further information we cannot answer. Please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 4):

Which one is correct depends on whether you mean it's your routine *now*, or your routine *in the past*. For example:

> I **woke up** at 3 every day last year.
>
> I have an early job, so I **wake up** at 3 every day.

(And as a side note, "every day" is correct here, not "everyday". "Everyday" is an adjective meaning "common, not special". For example, "I went to the store to buy some everyday goods like soap and shampoo.")

Comment: _I wake up at 3 every day  – that's no everyday wake-up time!_

Comment: Tell that to my kids

Answer (score 1):

'Wake up' implies that it is happening around the current time and is an ongoing action.
'Woke up' is the past tense implying that it is over.

For example:

> Normally I **wake up** at 6, but yesterday I **woke up** at 2 and I just couldn't sleep.

Comment: Just as one note, "woke up" could be an action that *was* ongoing in the past, but is not now. Given the OP stated "every day", either option could be correct, depending on the time reference.